# If column value is null then

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following calculation:

```
df['v1'] = df['dS']/df['dt']
```

dt Column value can be 0 therefore when I check df['v1'].max() gives me inf value.
To prevent this from happening, I want put following condition:

```
if df['dt']=0 then df['dS']/df['dt']=0 else calculate df['dS']/df['dt']
```

How do I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
df['v1'] = 0 
if df['dt'] != 0:
    df['v1'] = df['dS']/df['dt']
```

Comment: getting error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @MDoskarin what does `df['dt']` look like? I assumed it was an int - is it an array or something?

Comment: difference between two dates represented in seconds, type - float

Comment: @MDoskarin my answer assumed `df['dt']` was a single numerical value - based on that error it seems its actual a series of numerical values, so my answer doesn't apply. you may want to look at the duplicate question that was marked.

Comment: already checked that, doesn't work for me